# How to get value from JSON document record in M query (Power Connector)?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In M language (power connector), I download data and convert it to json like this

json = Json.Document(source)

I know for sure this json has 1 record like this

{Count: 3}

But If I return this, it shows 1 record like that. But as a test I changed it to return a number like 3 (hardcoded), and in power BI it showed just a value instead of a table. How can I return the value instead from the json document? Something like json[0]["Count"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, its just `json[count]`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30931867)

Comment: I am the author.